# varImp - Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, na.action = na.omit, drop.unused.level

Tags: r, knn, training-data, caret

I am trying to execute the varImp function for a "knn" and a "svmRadial" method using Caret. I obtain both models (knn & svmRadial), but when I try to execute the varImp funtion with them the following error message appears in my screen:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, na.action = na.omit,
> drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'y'

The R chunk for the knn model model and varImp function is the following:

**KNN Model**

```
set.seed(9)
grid_knn <- expand.grid(.k = c(3, 5, 7, 10, 15))

modelo_knn <- train(PER~., data=datos_entrenamiento, method="knn", preProc = c("center", "scale"), metric=metric,tuneGrid=grid_knn, trControl=control)

modelo_knn
```

**Output**

```
k-Nearest Neighbors 

1433 samples
   9 predictor

Pre-processing: centered (28), scaled (28) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 1146, 1146, 1148, 1146, 1146, 1146, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k   RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
   3  292.8288  0.3743854  37.60947
   5  300.1049  0.3013125  38.34929
   7  290.5655  0.2852039  37.64221
  10  280.7362  0.2525091  37.06593
  15  278.3909  0.1788722  38.38813
```

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was `k = 15`.

**varImp function with the Knn model**

```
var_imp_knn <- varImp(modelo_knn)
var_imp_knn
```

**Output**

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, na.action = na.omit,
> drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : invalid type (list) for variable 'y'

Can anybody help me to understand the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Best regards

Comment: After checking different sources it seems that it has to be with some specific modification in the data frame produce when using the transmute function, which generates the error when usin varImp. To avoid it, I suggest to include the following sentence for the datos_test before executing varImp: datos_test %<>% as.data.frame()

Comment: Can you specify which dataset is datos_test? I only see datos_entrenamiento in the data argument. Thanks!